# For loop is being skipped in Cocoa Touch

Tags: for-loop

I was doing some programming in Cocoa Touch and Objective-C, and now I have a really frustrating problem. I have a method in which there is a for-loop. Yet, every time I run the app in the iOS Simulator, the code in the loop isn't run, and it doesn't stop on any breakpoints within the loop. At first, I thought it was just in the method, but it appears now that it happens anywhere in the code. No for-loops work anywhere in any methods. Here is an example of one of my loops, and if you see anything wrong, I would appreciate the help.

```
for (int i = 0; i == 3; i++) {
    NSLog(@"This is a test.");
}
```

This might be something really dumb that I am missing, but I can't see anything that could be causing this. If you need more code, just ask, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition on a for loop causes the loop to run as long as the condition is true.

In the example you cited, the loop will never execute because i started off equal to zero, with the test condition i == 3.  Since i == 3 is immediately false, the loop does not run even once.

If your intention was to run the loop until i was three, then the test condition should be i < 3 making the entire for

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
```

Another way to think about this is that the loop will continue to run "while i < 3".

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of a for-loop—in your code, `i == 3`—is a test that is checked before each iteration of the loop.  If the test is false, the loop is ended.  Since i is 0 on the first iteration, `i == 3` is false.

You probably want either `i <= 3` or `i < 3` as your conditional.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop runs as long as the continuation condition is true.  Change "i==3" to "i <= 3".

Answer (score 0):

may be try

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++){
 NSLog("This is a test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop should look more like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    NSLog(@"This is a test.");
}
```